# What is total concentration of buffer used in derivation of buffer capacity?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, concentration, buffer

[ChemBuddy — The buffer capacity](http://www.chembuddy.com/?left=pH-calculation&right=pH-buffer-capacity) provides the following:

$$\ce{HA <=> H+ + A-}$$

> Total concentration of the buffer $c_\mathrm{buf}$ is given by
>
> $$c_\mathrm{buf} = [\ce{HA}] + [\ce{A-}]\tag{19.3}$$
>
> From dissociation constant definition we have
>
> $$[\ce{HA}] = \frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]}{K_\mathrm a}\tag{19.4}$$

But shouldn't

$$c_\mathrm{buf} = [\ce{HA}] + [\ce{A-}] + [\ce{H+}]?\tag{1}$$

The total concentration at equilibrium is

$$c(1 - \alpha) + 2c\alpha = c(1 + \alpha)\neq c,\tag{2}$$

hence the initial concentration of buffer is different from that at equilibrium.

Comment: you asked a question, then you replied correctly. The quantity of matter is conserved.

Comment: I don't understand. Does that mean they have given wrong equation? I have proved that its different in the last line.

Comment: At the equilibrium,  [HA]=c(1−α) and [A-]=cα. The quantity of matter of the specie A is conserved. So, the total amount of all species having A is c. So, c=[HA]+[A-]=c(1−α)+cα

Comment: Using the given definition of total concentration of buffer makes sense because that value does not change when the acid dissociates. Your proposed definition would make everything very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Initially in the solution the following equilibria exist

$$\ce{HA <=> H+ +A-}$$
and
$$\ce{H2O <=> H+ +OH-}$$

Let initial concentration of $\ce{HA}$ be $a_1$ and that of $\ce{A-}$ be $a_2$. Now to a litre of this buffer solution, let's say you have added $\mathrm dn$ moles of strong acid to it. The acid dissociation constant of $\ce{HA}$ be $K_a$ and the ionic product of water, $K_w$. By adding acid, you have disturbed the equilibrium, and from Le Chatelier's principle, both the reactions go backwards.

$$\ce{HA <<=> H+ + A- }\tag{1} \label{eqn:1}$$
$K_{eq}=K_a$
$$\ce{H2O <<=> H+ +OH-} \tag{2} \label{eqn:2}$$
$K_{eq}=K_w$

Let the new equilibrium concentrations of $\ce{HA},~\ce{A-},~\ce{H+},~\ce{OH-}$ be $a_1+\mathrm dx,~a_2-\mathrm dx,~\frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2}+\mathrm dn-\mathrm dx-\mathrm dy,~\frac{K_w\cdot a_2}{K_a.a_1} - \mathrm dy$ respectively.

At equilibrium, for $\ref{eqn:1}$,

$$K_a = \frac{(\frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2} +\mathrm dn-\mathrm dx-\mathrm dy)\cdot (a_2 - \mathrm dx)}{a_1+\mathrm dx} \tag{3} \label{eqn:3}$$

and for $\ref{eqn:2}$,

$$K_w = (\frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2}+\mathrm dn-\mathrm dx-\mathrm dy)\cdot (\frac{K_w\cdot a_2}{K_a.a_1}-\mathrm dy) \tag{4} \label{eqn:4}$$

Dividing $\ref{eqn:3}$ by $\ref{eqn:4}$, we get

$$(K_a)\cdot (\frac{K_w\cdot a_2}{K_a\cdot a_1}-\mathrm dy)=(K_w)\cdot (\frac{a_2-\mathrm dx}{a_1+\mathrm dx})\\
K_w\cdot a_2+\frac{K_w\cdot a_2}{a_1}\cdot \mathrm dx-K_aa_1\mathrm dy-K_a\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=K_wa_2-K_w\mathrm dx$$

Neglecting the term $K_a\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$, we get

$$dx= \frac{K_a\cdot {a_1}^2}{K_w(a_1+a_2)}\cdot \mathrm dy$$

and also from $\ref{eqn:3}$

$$K_a\cdot (a_1+\mathrm dx)=(\frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2}+\mathrm dn-\mathrm dx-\mathrm dy)\cdot (a_2-\mathrm dx)$$

Which on simplifying and neglecting terms of the type $\mathrm da\cdot \mathrm db$ will give,

$$\mathrm dn= (\frac{{K_a}^2\cdot {a_1}^2}{K_w\cdot {a_2}^2}+\frac{K_a\cdot {a_1}^2}{K_w\cdot (a_1+a_2)}+1)\cdot \mathrm dy \tag{5} \label{eqn:5}$$

By definition,

$\beta = \frac{\mathrm dn}{\mathrm{dpH}}$ and $\mathrm{pH}=-\log_{10} {[\ce{H+}]}$.

On differentiating this, we get

$$\mathrm{dpH} = \frac{-1}{[\ce{H+}]}\cdot \frac{1}{\log_e10}\cdot \mathrm d[\ce{H+}]$$

Substituting this in the definition of buffer capacity,

$$\beta = \frac{-\log_e10\cdot [\ce{H+}]\cdot \mathrm dn}{\mathrm d[\ce{H+}]} \tag{6} \label{eqn:6}$$

Here,

$$\mathrm d[\ce{H+}] = \mathrm dx+\mathrm dy-\mathrm dn = -\frac{{K_a}^2\cdot {a_1}^2}{{a_2^2}\cdot K_w}\cdot \mathrm dy$$

Substituting this expression of $\mathrm d[\ce{H+}]$ and $\mathrm dn$ from $\ref{eqn:5}$ in $\ref{eqn:6}$, we get,

$$\beta = \log_e10\cdot [\ce{H+}]\cdot \frac{(\frac{{K_a}^2\cdot {a_1}^2}{{a_2}^2\cdot K_w}+\frac{K_a\cdot {a_1^2}}{K_w\cdot (a_1 + a_2)} +1)}{\frac{{K_a}^2\cdot {a_1}^2}{{a_2}^2\cdot K_w}}\\
\beta = \log_e(10)[\ce{H+}](1 + \frac{K_w}{{[\ce{H+}]}^2} + \frac{{a_2}^2}{(a_1+a_2)\cdot K_a})\\
\beta = \log_e10( [\ce{H+}] + \frac{K_w}{[\ce{H+}]} + \frac{{a_2}^2\cdot [\ce{H+}]}{(a_1+a_2)\cdot K_a})$$

Substituting $[\ce{H+}]= \frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2}$ in the third term, we get

$$\beta = \log_e10( [\ce{H+}] + \frac{K_w}{[\ce{H+}]} + \frac{a_1\cdot a_2}{(a_1+a_2)})$$

Multiplying numerator and denominator of the third term with $K_a$,

$$\beta = \log_e10( [\ce{H+}] + \frac{K_w}{[\ce{H+}]} + \frac{K_a\cdot a_1\cdot a_2}{K_a\cdot (a_1+a_2)})$$

Taking $a_2$ common from the denominator and cancelling the $a_2$ in the numerator and substitute $\frac{k_a\cdot a_1}{a_2}=[\ce{H+}]$ and multiplying numerator and denominator with $[\ce{H+}]+K_a$, we get

$$\beta = \log_e10([\ce{H+}] + \frac{K_w}{[\ce{H+}]} + \frac{(\frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2})\cdot (K_aa_1+K_aa_2)}{{([\ce{H+}]+{K_a})}^2}$$

Taking $K_a$ out from the numerator and substituting $[\ce{H+}]=\frac{K_a\cdot a_1}{a_2}$, we get

$$\beta= \log_e10([\ce{H+}]+[\ce{OH-}]+ \frac{[\ce{H+}]K_a(a_1+a_2)}{([\ce{H+}]+K_a)^2})$$

So, in your expression, of course, $C_{\text{buf}}=a_1+a_2=[\ce{HA}]+[\ce{A-}]$ and not $[\ce{HA}]+[\ce{A-}]+[\ce{H+}]$

$$\beta= \log_e10([\ce{H+}]+[\ce{OH-}]+ \frac{[\ce{H+}]K_aC_{\text{buf}}}{([\ce{H+}]+K_a)^2})$$

You will get the same result if a small amount of base is added.

Comment: You should read [Which symbols are written in roman (upright) font and which are italicized?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/106377). I have corrected it for now. And it is better to use `$$...$$` (block mode) over `$... $` (single line mode) when writing long block of equations.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Thanks for the edit and I'll definitely look into it

Comment: Time flies. I asked this question like 5 years ago and I don't even understand what I even asked right now.